# How do you make fixtures work with minitest-rails version 0.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, fixtures, minitest

when I put

```
fixtures :all
```

in a model test, it generates the following error.

```
`<top (required)>': undefined method `fixtures' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Thanks

PS: I'm on rails 3.2.8

Comment: Do you have ActiveRecord loaded in your app? The fixtures plumbing is dependent on AR. https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails/blob/master/lib/minitest/rails.rb#L31-L42

Comment: It seems to be, defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) returns "constant" in my test file.

Answer (score 0):

Were you testing something which didn't inherit from ActiveRecord::Base?

I had this same issue.  I had a class which encapsulated some logic relating to a few ActiveRecord::Base models, but was itself not inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base.

In this scenario, test fixtures simply won't be loaded:  https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails/blob/master/lib/minitest/rails.rb#L93-L104

In short:

```
class RandomClassName
end
```

Will generate the error, but:

```
class RandomClassName < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Will not.